# Increase content size of UIScrollView when dragging object

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I have one UIView. Inside this view, i have added UIScrollView.And scrollview containing one UIButton.Everything is created by programmatically.Initially content size of scrollview is same as view size.User can drag button inside.Now if button reach at corner or any side of scrollview.If it is dragged there for more than 1 second than content size of scrollview should increase on that side.I dont have any idea about this technique or using which method ,we can get it.Please help me.Any hint will be appreciated.Thanking you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add UIPangesture recogniser for your UIButton. The handle of pasture recogniser needs to change the UIButton frame as well as UIScrollview frame. Take this sample initiative for your reference.

```
 UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
 [myButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
 [myButton addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
```

and your handle method should like this,

```
    -(IBAction)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
    {
     CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.view];
     sender.view.center = CGPointMake(sender.view.center.x + translation.x, 
                                         sender.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [sender setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

     //And check  sender x,y position with your `scrollview`,if it is crossed then you have to reset the `contentOffset`
     // Do the calculation like this
    if([sender.view.center].x>yourScrollviewXposition)
    {
  coordforX=([sender.view.center].x + translation.x);
  coordforY=([sender.view.center].y + translation.y);
//based on your calculated x, y position you have to calculate scrollview width and height
  [yourScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(width,height)];
   }
 }
```

Comment: but i dont want to change frame of button...just need to change content size of scrollview...

Comment: here what is recognizer? i mean instance of which class?how did you get it?

Comment: sender. it is nothing but the panGesture instance which is added in your button